# Not able to access Nexus 5X phone from Ubuntu 16.04 based laptop

Tags: usb, android

I was having Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop with Android Studio. I was able to work on Nexus 5X phone via a USB cable. Recently, I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. Now the system does not recognize the phone connected via a USB cable.

I have the file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules, having a line,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

When connected via USB cable, it is charging. But the lsusb output does not show the phone.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The adb devices command also does not show any device.

The syslog has some information.

```
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.144735] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.216705] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.392726] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.568743] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.640756] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.816754] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
May 29 18:14:49 bagpipe kernel: [ 2201.992739] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
May 29 18:14:50 bagpipe kernel: [ 2202.400707] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 21, error -32
May 29 18:14:50 bagpipe kernel: [ 2202.472733] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
May 29 18:14:50 bagpipe kernel: [ 2202.880708] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 22, error -32
May 29 18:14:50 bagpipe kernel: [ 2202.880793] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

How to get over this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was possibly a bad cable connecting the phone to the PC. With a different cable and latest Ubuntu 16.04 software, I am able to connect the phone with the PC and access the phone from Android Studio.

Comment: I had a really similar problem to you. Changing the cable also solved it for me. Perhaps a problem with the USB-C/USB-A cable I was using. I normal micro USB cable with a USB-C adapter worked for me.